# How to compress aт array into a vector and properly read from it

Tags: arrays, c, compression

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <malloc.h>


#define n 6
void insertarray(int arr[n][n])
{  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
  if(j==0){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      arr[i][j] = rand()%50;
    }
  }
  if(j==1){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(i==0){
          arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else if(i==5){
          arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else arr[i][j] = rand()%50;
    }
  }
  if(j==2){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(i==0 || i==1 || i==4 || i==5){
        arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else arr[i][j] = rand()%50;
    }
  }
  if(j==3){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(i==0 || i==1 || i==4 || i==5){
        arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else arr[i][j] = rand()%50;
    }
  }
  if(j==4){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(i==0){
          arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else if(i==5){
          arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else arr[i][j] = rand()%50;
    }
  }
  if(j==5){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      arr[i][j] = rand()%50;
    }
  }
}

}

int NewIndex(int x, int y)     //пересчет индексов
{   int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++) j+= n-i;
    return j+y-x;
}
void Put(int vec [], int x, int y, int v)  // Запись в вектор (сжатие)
{  if (y >=x) vec[NewIndex(x, y)] = v;
}
int Get(int vec [], int x, int y) // Чтение из вектора
{  if (y >=x) return vec[NewIndex(x, y)];
   else return 0;
}

void printarray(int a[n][n])
{    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    printf("%3i", a[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
     }
}
int main()
{  int vec[n*n/2+n/2];
   int array[n][n];
   insertarray(array);
   printarray(array);
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j <n ; j++)
         Put(vec, i, j, array[i][j]);   //сжатие массива
   for(int i = 0; i < n*n/2+n/2; i++)   //выдача результата сжатия
  printf("%3i", vec[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    { for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)  //чтение из сжатого представления
       printf("%3i", Get(vec,i,j));
      printf("\n");
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Well, i have a totally working code which firstly made an array which contained the null elements under the main diagonal, compresses it into a vector and then reads from it. But now i have to make an array which contains null elements in two triangles above and under the crossing of diagonal.
it must looking like this

```
6 0 0 0 0 2
3 1 0 0 4 3 
2 9 2 1 5 6
7 8 6 2 4 6
8 7 0 0 2 1
9 0 0 0 0 9
```

and the first step of making it was succesful: i generate such array, but the problem is that it doesn't compress it normally. it needs to convert all the elements that are not in the triangles but it compresses like it's having null elements only under the main diagonal. the problem with the reading is that it reads the array like the past one but also with the triangle of null element above the crossing. can you help me redoing the code? i've added a picture of running my program
[image: the result of running my program]

Comment: A "[massive](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/massive)"?

Comment: Yeah,my bad. i didn't look properly on what i've written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this pattern, we test that our current *column* is within the range of our current *row* relative to either edge, up to our halfway point. We then invert our calculations past there.

Converting a matrix to and from an array is just a matter of iterating through your matrix bounds, writing/reading to/from the array, and advancing your array pointer.

To compress the matrix we need to apply the inverse of our calculations as a filter, storing only non-zero values. Decompressing follows the same logic as our initial `fill` operation, but sourcing from an array instead.

Note that the size calculation done here:

```
int vec[n*n/2 + n/2];
```

Does not create a correctly sized array that for the results (for size `6` this produces `21`, when you need at least `24`). Take a look at the function `non_zero_count` below for an accurate calculation for finding the amount of non-zeroes this pattern produces for any given size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void fill_matrix(int sz, int m[sz][sz]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
            if ((i <= sz / 2 && j > i && j < sz - 1 - i) ||
                (i > sz / 2 && j > sz - i - 1 && j <= i - 1))
                m[i][j] = 0;
            else
                m[i][j] = rand() % 99 + 1;
        }
    }
}

void pack_matrix(int *array, int sz, int m[sz][sz]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            if (!(i <= sz / 2 && j > i && j < sz - 1 - i) &&
                !(i > sz / 2 && j > sz - i - 1 && j <= i - 1))
                *array++ = m[i][j];
}

void unpack_matrix(int *array, int sz, int m[sz][sz]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
            if ((i <= sz / 2 && j > i && j < sz - 1 - i) ||
                (i > sz / 2 && j > sz - i - 1 && j <= i - 1))
                m[i][j] = 0;
            else
                m[i][j] = *array++;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int sz, int m[sz][sz]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        printf("[ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            printf("%02d ", m[i][j]);
        printf("]\n");
    }
}

int non_zero_count(int n) {
    int is_even = n % 2 == 0;

    return (n * n) - ((is_even ? n : n - 1) / 2) * (n - (is_even ? 2 : 1));
}

#define MSZ 6
int main(void) {
    int matrix[MSZ][MSZ];
    int matrix2[MSZ][MSZ];
    int array[non_zero_count(MSZ)];

    srand(time(NULL));

    fill_matrix(MSZ, matrix);
    print_matrix(MSZ, matrix);

    puts("----");

    pack_matrix(array, MSZ, matrix);
    unpack_matrix(array, MSZ, matrix2);
    print_matrix(MSZ, matrix2);
}
```

Output:

```
[ 59 00 00 00 00 79 ]
[ 91 50 00 00 25 37 ]
[ 24 85 19 23 24 25 ]
[ 67 97 54 14 12 34 ]
[ 44 78 00 00 14 01 ]
[ 25 00 00 00 00 12 ]
----
[ 59 00 00 00 00 79 ]
[ 91 50 00 00 25 37 ]
[ 24 85 19 23 24 25 ]
[ 67 97 54 14 12 34 ]
[ 44 78 00 00 14 01 ]
[ 25 00 00 00 00 12 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this will surely help me a lot, but can you say how this suggestion can help me to fix the problem with the compressing the matrix and reading it from the compressed state?

Comment: well this is the right thing. well the last problem is that i need also a string of all the positive numbers inside a matrix in the output but i'm sure that i can make it myself. Thank you for the spent time and answer

Comment: @Anim233 I've thought about this more, and I think my updated answer is more likely what you're trying achieve (storing the matrix without its zeroes).